# Может ли Bundle быть null?

Tags: java, android, activity

При создании нового Activity на вход методу onCreate() подается объект типа Bundle.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

В учебнике "Android programming: the big nerd ranch guide (3rd edition)" показано, как при восстановлении состояния, допустим при повороте экрана, делается проверка savedInstanceState на null:

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mCurrentIndex = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY_INDEX, 0);
    }
```

Разве может ссылка иметь значение null, а если может, то в каких случаях? Потому что даже не сохраняя состояние Activity, проверка на не null у меня всегда была true.

Comment: Может - когда активность создаётся без сохранённого состояния (чистый запуск, а не выход из фона). При поворотах экрана скорее всего нет, потому что кое что сохраняется и восстанавливается даже без Вашего участия, особенно если наследуете активность из библиотек поддержки.

Comment: @woesss, это ко всем активностям относится, или только которая создается самой первой?

Comment: @Vennic, ко всем.

Comment: @woesss, спасибо, буду сегодня проверять, вы можете оформить свой комментарий как ответ?